# Find the volume of a shape whose base is defined as the area between graphs and whose height is defined as another function?

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of a shape whose base is defined as the area between graphs (for e.g. the area between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$) and whose height is defined as another function (e.g. $\cos x$)? This graphic could help you. The ||'s in the end means that the top edges are parallel.

[image: volume gif]

Comment: This is quite vague. What **exactly** are you having difficulties with?

Comment: @Andrei Say the base of the shape is the area between 2 graphs (in my examples case the area between `sinx` and `cosx` are very similar to a triangle) and it's height is not fixed, instead the height at a certain point is the third function(in my example cosx). I'm guessing the confusion is at the height function, if so I'm trying to say that the base is being extended at each point in the x-axis(in reference to the base i.e. the area between graph) to its corresponding value at the height function. So essentially its just extending the plane at variable heights throughout the whole base.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a region $D$ in the $xy$-plane described as the area between two functions $y = l(x)$ and $y = u(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$. I.e., $$D = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid a\le x \le b\text{ and }l(x) \le y \le u(x)\}$$

And you are also given a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) \ge 0$ for $(x,y) \in D$, and are looking for the volume of the solid $$E = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid (x,y) \in D\text{ and } 0 \le z \le f(x,y)\}$$

This can be determined by the iterated integral
$$\begin{align}V &= \iiint_E 1\,dV \\&= \int_a^b\int_{l(x)}^{u(x)}\int_0^{f(x,y)} 1\,dz\,dy\,dx\\&=\int_a^b\int_{l(x)}^{u(x)}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I think there is one issue with this answer. I'm asking that the height function is a one dimensional function (i.e. of form f(x), not f(x,y) or technically ignoring the y), so we are just looking at the x-axis for managing the height, so looking at the shape(the base) at eye-level and extending the line/ribbon on the x-axis to the y-axis towards the z-axis with it's corresponding value in f(X). Or more simply put, the top of the shape should be sort of flat, without any variations in height, or the top edges are completely parallel to each other.

Comment: Why is that an issue? That is just an extra condition on the function $f$. The expression is still the same. The only difference is that since $f(x,y)$ depends on $x$ only, you can write it as just $f(x)$. It makes the integration easier as well, since $f$ is constant with respect to $y$, so you can pull it out of the $y$-integration to end up with $$\int_a^b f(x)(u(x) = l(x))\, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

With those conditions you could find the volume without knowing anything about double or triple integrals by just using intuition. So if I understood it well, you just have a $f(x)$ function on the `xy`-plane and you "drag" it out to fill the space down the `z`-axis. Then the volume is surface on `xy`-plane times the length on `z`-axis.
$$V = S_{xy} \cdot z = z \int_a^b f(x)dx$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are coordinates on `x`-axis.